# Checking for Unique Value in Object/Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Me again. I've finally gotten to the final part with my script I've been writing, and the only thing now that I need to try and do is check for unique values.

Below is the script that I've written, however it is not working. Any help would be appreciated. It doesn't appear to respond at all since I've added the 'for' loop. I am trying to check for duplicates in the array.

```
var garrCust = []; // an array of id -> {id:"", name:"", amount:""}

function addCust(){
    var custID = document.getElementById("custid").value;
    var custName = document.getElementById("custname").value;
    var custAmount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var i;

    if(!custID){
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "ID Cannot be Blank";
        return false;}

    for(i = 0; i < garrCust.length; i++){
        if(garrCust[i].hasOwnProperty(custID)){
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "ID already Exists!";
            return false;}
        else{
            garrCust.push({id: custID, name: custName, amount: custAmount});
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Added ID " + custID;
            return true;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error in your console?

Comment: _"however it is not working"_ you need to actually describe what exactly isn't working

Comment: What is the script supposed to do? What out put are you getting versus what you expect?

Comment: "Me again." When writing a question on Stack Overflow, assume people have never read any of your previous questions. We get > 12,000 questions a day. Please read [ask] (and the articles linked therein) for information on what we expect from questions.

Comment: Also `.hasOwnProperty(custID)` checks if an object has a property named with whatever `custID` holds, it doesn't check the object's `id` property to see if it contains that value, so start there

Comment: Hi all. Apologies. The deal with this particular function, is that it should be checking garrCust.id to see if the value of custID already exists. If it does, then it should error, otherwise it should should push the values from the 3 cust variables into the array using the garrCust.push line.

Currently however, it is not doing anything. It's not throwing an error, or processing any information.

Comment: @ChrisMcKechnie Do you even call the function ? Show us the HTML pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop should iterate over the whole array to check if the ID exists.

The first time you add a customer it will not go inside your loop because the array is empty

Please find below a working snippet

```js
var garrCust = []; // an array of id -> {id:"", name:"", amount:""}

function addCust() {
  var custID = document.getElementById("custid").value;
  var custName = document.getElementById("custname").value;
  var custAmount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var list = document.getElementById("list");
  
  //Input ID is empty
  if (!custID) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "ID Cannot be Blank";
    return false;
  }
  
  //Create the customer object
  var myCustomer = {
    "id": custID,
    "name": custName,
    "amount": custAmount
  };

  //Check if ID already exists
  for(let i=0; i<garrCust.length;i++){
    if(garrCust[i].id === custID){
      output.innerHTML = "ID already exists !";
      output.style.color = "red";
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  //ID was not found thus add the new customer
  garrCust.push(myCustomer);
  output.innerHTML = "Customer added";
  output.style.color = "green";
  list.innerHTML += custID + " - ";
}
```

```html
ID
<input type="text" id="custid">Name
<input type="text" id="custname">Amount
<input type="number" id="amount">

<input type="submit" onclick="addCust()" value="Add customer">

<br/>

<p id="output"></p>

<p id="list"></p>
```